# Transit via Hong Kong

Tags: transit, japan, hong-kong, refugees, afghan-citizens

I am from Afghanistan and I have a refugee travel document issued in Japan. 
I have flight from Japan to Germany via Hong Kong, with a 7 hour layover in Hong Kong. Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes you need a visa by virtue of your nationality, per the notes at the end of the visa requirements table. You might be able to transit with your travel document direct by air, providing you don’t leave the transit area, providing your document qualifies as a ‘stateless person travel document’, which is listed towards the end of the table.

As commented by @David, the visa requirements table isn’t entirely clear. I’d recommend you contact the Hong Kong Embassy in Japan for clarification.

Comment: The HK page says two different things. The chart's column header says "Always require VISA, except in direct transit by air and when the person does not leave the airport transit area." Just below this, in the "Afghanistan" section, the text is "Visa Required*", with an asterisk. The asterisked note below says "All nationals are required to hold a valid visa for the HKSAR for whatever purpose (including those who are in transit and remain on the airside)." That's 1 vote for "visa necessary," and one for "no visa necessary." I don't know what the OP should do.

Comment: @David I believe the OP would qualify as a holder of a stateless person travel document, which appears at the end of the list. I agree it’s confusing, I will amend my answer